Solving a system of ODEs in Python
I'm trying to solve this ODE system, I'm a little confused because sol.success returns False and print("Length of time points:", len(solution.t)) prints 1.
I can't see where I'm wrong. I tried to change t_span, the constants, but nothing works. I know the initial conditions are reasonable (for this test). What could I do?
import numpy as np
import sympy as sp
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import odeint

t_span = [0, 1000]
#dt = 0.1
t_eval = np.arange(0, 1000, 1)

# constants
Mp =1
n = 1
Lambda = 1
Cupsilon =0.014

# Condições iniciais
phi0 = 12.327
dphi0 =-7.956* Lambda**(1/2)
rad0 =36.9622 * Lambda
a0 = 1
H0 = np.sqrt(Mp**2/2*(dphi0**2/2+phi0**(2*n-1)+rad0))
k=100*H0


J11_0=0
J12_0=0
J13_0=0
J14_0 = 0
J15_0=0
J21_0=0
J22_0=0
J23_0=0
J24_0=0
J25_0= 0
J31_0=0
J32_0=0
J33_0=0
J34_0=0
J35_0= 0
J41_0=0
J42_0=0
J43_0=0
J44_0=0
J45_0= 0
J51_0=0
J52_0=0
J53_0=0
J54_0 = 0
J55_0 = 0

# System of odes
def sistema_matricial_m(t, w):
    phi, dphi, rad, a, J11, J12, J13, J14, J15, J21, J22, J23, J24, J25, J31, J32, J33, J34, J35, J41, J42, J43, J44, J45, J51, J52, J53, J54,J55 = w

    dpot = Lambda * phi**(2 *n - 1)
    ddpot = Lambda * (2 * n - 1) * phi**(2 * n - 2)
    dpot0 = Lambda * phi0**(2 * n - 1)

    H = np.sqrt(Mp**2 / 2 * (dphi**2 / 2 + dpot + rad))
    H0 = np.sqrt(Mp**2 / 2 * (dphi0**2 / 2 + dpot0 + rad0))
    k = 100 * H0
    gstar = 12.5
    Cr = gstar * np.pi**2 / 30
    T = (rad / Cr)**(1 / 4)

    Alpha = 0
    Beta = 1

    gamma = Cupsilon * phi**(Alpha) * T**Beta
    gammaT = Beta*Cupsilon*(T)**(-1+Beta)
    gammaPhi = 0
    Q = gamma / (3 * H)


    fpsi = 1 + (k**2 / (3 * a**2 * H**2)) - (dphi / H)**2 / (6 * Mp**2)
    frho = 1 / (6 * Mp**2 * H**2)
    fdphi = (dphi / H) / (6 * Mp**2)
    fphi =dpot / (6 * Mp**2 * H**2)

    gpsi = gamma * H * (dphi / H)**2 - k**2 / (3 * a**2) * ((2 * Mp**2 * k**2 / (a**2 * H**2)) - (dphi / H)**2)
    grho = 4 - gammaT * H * T * (dphi / H)**2 / (4 * rad) - k**2 / (3 * a**2 * H**2)
    gdphi = -(k**2 / (3 * a**2) + 2 * gamma * H) * (dphi / H)
    gphi = -k**2 / (3 * a**2 * H**2) * (3 * (dphi / H) * H**2 + (dpot)) - H * gammaPhi * (dphi / H)**2

    hpsi = 2 * (dpot) / H**2 + gamma / H * (dphi / H)
    hdphi = 3 + gamma / H - 1 / (6 * Mp**2 * H**2) * (3 * dphi**2 + 4 * rad)
    hrho = (T * gammaT / (4 * rad * H)) * (dphi / H)
    hphi = (k**2 / (H**2 * a**2)) + ((ddpot) / (H**2)) + gammaPhi / (H) * (dphi / H)

    Grho = grho + k**2 / (3 * a**2 * H**2)
    Gpsi =gpsi + k**2 / (3 * a**2) * (2 * Mp**2 * k**2 / (a**2 * H**2) - (dphi / H)**2)
    Gphi = gphi + k**2 / (3 * a**2 * H**2) * (3 * H**2 * (dphi / H) + (dpot))
    Gdphi =gdphi + k**2 / (3 * a**2) * (dphi / H)

    A = np.array([[Grho + 4 * rad * frho, -H * k**2 / (a**2 * H**2), Gpsi + 4 * rad * fpsi, Gphi + 4 * rad * fphi, Gdphi + 4 * rad * fdphi],
                  [1 / (3 * H), 3, 4 * rad / (3 * H), gamma * dphi, 0],
                  [frho, 0, fpsi, fphi, fdphi],
                  [0, 0, 0, 0, -1],
                  [hrho + 4 * (dphi / H) * frho, 0, hpsi + 4 * (dphi / H) * fpsi, hphi + 4 * (dphi / H) * fphi, hdphi + 4 * (dphi / H) * fdphi]])

    B = np.array([[-(dphi / H) * np.sqrt(2 * gamma * T * H / a**3)], [0], [0], [0], [np.sqrt(2 * gamma * T / (a * H)**3)]])

    J = np.array([[J11, J12, J13, J14, J15], [J21, J22, J23, J24, J25], [J31, J32, J33, J34, J35], [J41, J42, J43, J44, J45], [J51, J52, J53, J54, J54]])

    matrix = ((-np.dot(A, J) - np.dot(np.transpose(A), J)) + np.dot(np.transpose(B),B))

    dphidt = dphi / H
    ddphidt = -3 * (1 + Q) * dphi - dpot / H
    draddt = -4 * rad + 3 * Q * dphi**2
    dadt = a
    eq1 = matrix[0,0]
    eq2 = matrix[0,1]
    eq3 = matrix[0,2]
    eq4 = matrix[0,3]
    eq5 = matrix[0,4]
    eq6 = matrix[1,0]
    eq7 = matrix[1,1]
    eq8 =matrix[1,2]
    eq9 = matrix[1,3]
    eq10 =matrix[1,4]
    eq11 = matrix[2,0]
    eq12 = matrix[2,1]
    eq13 = matrix[2,2]
    eq14 = matrix[2,3]
    eq15 = matrix[2,4]
    eq16 =matrix[3,0]
    eq17 = matrix[3,1]
    eq18 = matrix[3,2]
    eq19 = matrix[3,3]
    eq20 = matrix[3,4]
    eq21 =matrix[4,0]
    eq22 = matrix[4,1]
    eq23 = matrix[4,2]
    eq24 =matrix[4,3]
    eq25 = matrix[4,4]
    
    dwdt = [dphidt, ddphidt, draddt, dadt, eq1, eq2, eq3, eq4, eq5, eq6, eq7, eq8, eq9, eq10, eq11, eq12, eq13, eq14, eq15, eq16, eq17, eq18, eq19, eq20, eq21, eq22, eq23, eq24,eq25]
    return dwdt

# ics
w0 = [phi0, dphi0, rad0, a0, J11_0, J12_0, J13_0, J14_0, J15_0, J21_0, J22_0, J23_0, J24_0,
      J25_0, J31_0, J32_0, J33_0, J34_0, J35_0, J41_0, J42_0, J43_0, J44_0, J45_0, J51_0, J52_0, J53_0, J54_0, J55_0]

# time
#t = np.linspace(0, 100, 1000)

# solving EDOs
sol = solve_ivp(sistema_matricial_m, t_span, w0, t_eval=t_eval, method='RK45',rtol=1e-6)
#sol=odeint(sistema_matricial_m, w0,t)

sol.success


Welcome to [so]. We don't provide generalized debugging services. We can assist with specific issues. Please use the following references on debugging your code to narrow your problem to a specific issue. How to debug small programs, Six Debugging Techniques for Python Programmers

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
